# Emploi de « Notes sur .. » pour exprimer « Notes de cours »

Tags: vocabulaire

Puis-je utiliser l'expression :

> Notes sur la mécanique des milieux continus.

comme traduction de la phrase ci-après :

> *Notes on continuum mechanics*.

Il me paraît que l'emploi le plus fréquent du substantif *note* est pour l'équivalent de *grade* en anglais.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Oui, *notes* peut être utilisé sans ambiguïté ici.

S'il avait signifié *grade*, on aurait écrit :

> Notes **en** mécanique des milieux continus.